Inference of overloaded functions
TypeScript inference of return type of overloaded functions seems to be wrong under certain circumstances. See this simple example:
type TA = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
}

type TB = {
    b: number,
}

function fn(arg: TB): string
function fn(arg: TA): number
function fn(arg: any) {
    return 1 as any;
}


const myArg: TA = {
    a: 10,
    b: 20
}
const result = fn(myArg)

Visual Studio Code and TypeScript Playground infer the type string for result.
If you change the order of overloaded functions, the type of result is number.
For me it seems like TS is only checking presence of all attributes of first overloaded function suitable to determine the return type.
I expect the return type of result to be number.
Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Overloads are tried in order, the first match wins AFAIC. But this is unsafe anyway, and it's a pity TS allows such declaration.

Are you aware that TA extends TB? That is, every TA is also a TB?  (so const alsoMyArg: TB = myArg; compiles with no error.) If so then it's just as the above commenter says: overload order matters; the first one that matches wins. If not then we need to talk about structural typing and/or excess properties and you can decide to change TA to distinguish it from TB like this playground link shows. How would you like to proceed here?

Thank you for the answers.
I expected Typescript to distinguish between different type definitions independently from their structure. I haven't read about structurlat typing yet.

The problem that TA extends TB, read about structural typing
To solve the problem you could either to add a fake prop to distinguish types:
type TA = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
}

type TB = {
    b: number,
    isTB?: never; // add fake prop for structural typing
}

function fn(arg: TB): string
function fn(arg: TA): number
function fn(arg: any) {
    return 1 as any;
}


const result = fn({ // number
    a: 10,
    b: 20
})

const result2 = fn({ // string
    b: 10
});

or use strict types:
type TA = {
    a: number,
    b: number,
}

type TB = {
    b: number
}

type StrictType<A extends object, B extends object> = A extends B ? B extends A ? A : never : never;

function fn<T extends TB>(arg: StrictType<T, TB>): string
function fn<T extends TA>(arg: StrictType<T, TA>): number
function fn(arg: any) {
    return 1 as any;
}


const result = fn({ // number
    a: 10,
    b: 20
})

const result2 = fn({ // string
    b: 10
});

